# No Response from Azure Web Application Firewal

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an App Service hosted in azure and I need to secure that using Azure's Web Application Firewall (WAF). I've created the WAF and also specified the app service's FQDN but when I hit that from the browser I get a timeout response after ~3mins.

I've validated that I can hit the AppService using the http://FQDN. The WAF's BackendHttpSetting is configured for HTTP port 80. The listener is also configured for http 80. Ive tried hitting the WAF endpoint using the IP as well as the {guid}.cloudapp.net

I'm out of ideas now.

Any pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Support for Azure Web Application requires additional configuration on backend setting and probe for correctly overriding Host headers from incoming requests. This is documented at [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-overview) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell) for a working example.